# Stop execution, close form and return to caller

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method on a child form that saves a data record. If I encounter certain errors I want to close the child form and halt execution in the current method and return to the main form. When I use this.Close(); the form closes but execution of the method in the closed form does not halt.

Parent form code:

```
SavePermanentRecord spr = new SavePermanentRecord(this);
spr.Show();
```

Child form code:

```
if(path == null)
{
  MessageBox.Show("There was a problem saving the file to the path: \r" + basePath + folderName);
  this.Close();
  //I need the method to stop here and any other processing in this form halted.
}
```

How do I halt execution and close the current (child) code and return to the parent form?

Comment: add a return statement after the this.Close() ?

Comment: Add more code, we cant tell the scope of execution from what you have posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you call that line your code will still continue executing. To stop it, simply put `return;` after it.

```
    if(path == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a problem saving the file to the path: \r" + basePath + folderName);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes I am amazed how the simplest of solutions evades me! Perfect! Thank you.